# Display DIV's on Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have 2 div elements, and I want to add something on the Div 2 that when I Click on that Div, it will Display Div 1, so both DIV's will be visible when clicking Div 2!
Div 2 should remain visible all the time, but when I click on DIV 2, it should display Div 1!

I want a JS script!

```css
.box1 {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: rgba(234, 21, 56, 0.3);
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid #ea1538;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gainsboro;
}

.box1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.box1:hover {
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#cover1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}

.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: rgba(234, 21, 56, 0.3);
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid #ea1538;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gainsboro;
}

.box2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.box2:hover {
  transition: ease 0.5s;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#cover2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <img src="/images/Books/book_bg.jpg" alt="cover" id="cover1" />
  <h3 class="desc1">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et iste ipsum harum beatae dolor fugit repudiandae a quaerat doloremque pariatur, suscipit molestias ipsa minus. Non explicabo quam quasi illo accusamus aliquid, reiciendis autem? Quas odio hic
    pariatur necessitatibus nobis nisi fugiat ab voluptate. Perferendis maiores quisquam cumque quod aspernatur ipsa?
  </h3>
</div>


<div class="box2">
  <button type="button" id="box2btn" onclick="href='window.location.https://www.facebook.com'">
             <img src="/images/Books/book_bg.jpg" alt="cover" id="cover2" />
             <h3>
               Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi
               natus quidem perferendis architecto sapiente, eius, praesentium, odio
               illo provident quos nostrum quaerat! Placeat saepe, blanditiis id
               assumenda ab autem in unde maxime alias, obcaecati distinctio expedita
               veritatis deserunt atque exercitationem quasi dolorum eum quas. Voluptas
               consequatur nisi sint porro quos?
             </h3>
      </div>
```

Comment: `I want a JS script! Can you help` This is not a we code it for free service. If you have a specific problem, feel free to ask it tough!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - .  If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @cloned: It kinda develops into one tho. Just gotta wait for someone seeking sloppy points.

Comment: I am still new in HTML and CSS and I have no knowledge on JS, I am gonna learn it after mastering these two first! Thank you for your advise tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go https://jsfiddle.net/byr0kqL5/

The simple function

```
function addNewDiv() {
   const box1 = document.getElementById("box1-content") //find element with id `box1-content`
   box1.classList.remove("display-none"); //make box 1 visible by `display-none` removal
}
```

but you need to add this style

```
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

Your box 1 will be like this

```
<div class="box1 display-none" id="box1-content"></div>
```

Lastly, your box 2 needs to have `onclick` event

```
<div class="box2" onclick="addNewDiv()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add this attribute to Div2 :

```
onclick="showDiv()"
```

and add the id and class to Div1

```
id="div1"
class="hide"
```

JavaScript :

```
function showDiv() {
   div1=document.getElementById("div1");
   div1.classList.remove("hide");
}
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
   display: none;
}
```